# Inheritence using sub-table with a single column

Tags: inheritance, database-design

For my data, using the Table-Per-Type pattern would result in 'subclass' tables with only one column (primary key of the parent table).

By not having an autoincrementing primary key in the subtable, i can skip that table when doing joins for reads, but still have strong typing for inserts in other tables with a foriegn relationship.

My case is a bit complex, but boils down to a the following example:

- Person class with a 'Customer' and 'Salesrep' subclasses.
- Person table has an autoincrement id and  name/address/phone. Subclasses have no specialized info (just foreign key to Person table), just indicate type.
- a CustomerOrder table can have one foreign key reference to the Customer table and one to the Salesrep table

That way, when I insert a customer order it enforces that I don't get the wrong type of Person for those two fields.
But when I do a 'cascading' read on a CustomerOrder, I only join to Person without needing the extra joins to the 'Customer' and 'Salesrep' tables.

**Is there anything wrong with this approach? Is this a known/named pattern?**

Seems weird to have tables with only one column and I don't see a lot of people doing that but I can't see anything wrong with it. I could do it as a type field in the person table, but that's awkward to make the foreign keys work in other tables like CustomerOrder (would need a compound key?).

(I guess I have to ensure in code that the same person doesn't appear in both the Customer and SalesRep tables, but that's easier than trying to enforce things in all the tables that reference Person)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, there is nothing wrong with your approach. You are following the *Joined Tables Inheritance* pattern where subtables (representing subclasses) are joined to their supertable via their primary key being also a foreign key referencing the supertable.

Of course, in such a case where subtables do not have many (or any) additional columns, one would normally use the *Single Table Inheritance* approach with just one table `persons` and a `type` (or `category`) column. But, as you note, this would imply constraints on the attributes `customer` and `salesRep`of the `CustomerOrder` class, which could not be implemented as simple foreign keys of the `customer_orders` table. Rather, it seems that triggers would be needed to enforce these constraints.

So, there is a trade-off between the more complex Joined Tables Inheritance representation with a simpler implementation of the referential integrity constraints for `customer` and `salesRep`, versus a simpler representation (with Single Table Inheritance) with a more complex implementation of the referential integrity constraints.